# Using step with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lm

I am able to carry out something like the following:

```
foo=data.frame(y=rnorm(100),x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100),x3=rnorm(100))
full=lm(foo$y ~ foo$x1 + foo$x2 + foo$x3)
nil=lm(foo$y ~ 1)
fwd=step(nil,scope=list(lower=formula(nil),upper=formula(full)),direction='forward')
```

But I'm working with data.table like so:

```
library(data.table)
foo=data.table(y=rnorm(100),x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100),x3=rnorm(100))
full=foo[,lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)]
nil=foo[,lm(y ~ 1)]
fwd=foo[,step(nil,scope=list(lower=formula(nil),upper=formula(full)),direction='forward')]
```

And I get the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x1' not found
```

But `x1` is defined inside the J expression above for data.table - is there a way around this without having to convert my table to a data.frame?

Comment: See SO Post: [using lm(my_formula) inside [.data.table's j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311600/using-lmmy-formula-inside-data-tables-j).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to pass `.SD` as the `data` argument to `lm` within `[.data.table`, as otherwise `data.table` optimizes it's`j` argument to only use what is referenced.

```
foo=data.table(y=rnorm(100),x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100),x3=rnorm(100))
full=foo[,lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3,data=.SD)]
nil=foo[,lm(y ~ 1,data=.SD)]
fwd <- step(nil,scope=list(lower=formula(nil),upper=formula(full)),direction='forward')

# using .SD means all columns are available
ls(environment(formula(nil))
## [1] "x1" "x2" "x3" "y" 

# compared with
nil.noSD =foo[,lm(y ~ 1)]
ls(environment(formula(nil.noSD)))
## [1] "y"
```

Note that data.table and `lm` and the scoping rules for update.formula etc don't always "play nicely"

See [Why is using update on a lm inside a grouped data.table losing its model data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096811/why-is-using-update-on-a-lm-inside-a-grouped-data-table-losing-its-model-data) for an example